# How to generate a thread dump that looks similar to what you get from JVisualVM?

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm

If I want to generate a thread dump and log it within my application (for diagnostic purposes), are there any utilities for generating one, or am I stuck cobbling together my own?

Comment: Why not use visualvm? It's part of the jdk distribution

Comment: Because I want my application to do it itself based on certain conditions.

Comment: you might want to check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/240217/594406

Answer (score 1):

This is a semi-duplicate of this question.  Check out my answer here:

> [Generate a Java thread dump without restarting.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12842344/generate-a-java-thread-dump-without-restarting/12842509#12842509)

This does an approximation of the output seen when you do a `kill -QUIT <my-pid>`.  Not sure how much that matches the JVisualVM output.

The full code for the [Thread stack dump method is posted on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/uS5jYpd4).  A sample of the code is in the question listed.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `StackTraceElement[] cause = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();` as recommended in [Determining Current Call Stack (For Diagnostic Purposes)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/706292/772000).

Related Q/A:

- [Determining Current Call Stack (For Diagnostic Purposes)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/706292/772000)
- [How to get Java Call Stack of a running application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14705451/772000)
- [Request java heap dump (core dump) from within application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818897/request-java-heap-dump-core-dump-from-within-application/1818941#1818941)

Comment: Note that you should post question as duplicate instead of using it as your own answer.

Comment: Also, none of the links posted helps OP to get a thread dump from the running application.

Comment: Yes, but that's the starting point for cobbling together my own solution.  I wanted to know if there were any libraries that will generate the full dump with thread names, locks, etc., formatted in a way that most thread dump analysis tools will understand.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza : I agree, this is a duplicate question. I won't mind if its flagged for close.

Comment: @Jun-DaiBates-Kobashigawa that's covered in the possible duplicate question link.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using this.  Not sure if it's exactly what you want.

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import java.lang.management.ThreadInfo;
import java.lang.management.ThreadMXBean;
public class ThreadDumper
{
    public static String dumpThreads()
    {
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);           
        try
        {
            ThreadMXBean bean = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean();
            ThreadInfo[] threadInfos = bean.getThreadInfo(bean.getAllThreadIds(), Integer.MAX_VALUE);
            for (int i = 0; i < threadInfos.length; i++)
            {
                ThreadInfo threadInfo = threadInfos[i];
                pw.print(threadInfo);
            }

            pw.println("----------------------------------------");
            pw.println();

            long[] deadlockedIds = bean.findMonitorDeadlockedThreads();
            if(deadlockedIds == null || deadlockedIds.length == 0)
            {
                pw.println("Detected 0 deadlocked threads.");
            }
            else
            {
                pw.println("Detected " + deadlockedIds.length + " deadlocked threads:");
                threadInfos = bean.getThreadInfo(deadlockedIds, 0);
                for (int i = 0; i < threadInfos.length; i++)
                {
                    ThreadInfo threadInfo = threadInfos[i];
                    pw.print(threadInfo);
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            pw.println("----------------------------------------");
            pw.println("Exception occurred while taking thread dump:");
            e.printStackTrace(pw);
            pw.println("----------------------------------------");
        }

        return sw.toString();
    }
}
```